# How to validate the parameter is uppercase in Jenkins using ANT

Tags: jenkins, parameters, ant, uppercase

I have a Jenkins build and in that I am providing a build parameter with uppercase value **(Build parameter should be uppercase always)**, by chance if a user is providing a lower case value, the build should gets failed.

Kindly provide inputs on how to check the provided Jenkins build parameter provided is uppercase or a lowercase using **ANT**. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using Ant's `matches` condition. A nested `regexp` is used in the below example to avoid repetition.

```
<target name="check-uppercase">
    <property name="test1" value="lowercase" />
    <property name="test2" value="MixedCase" />
    <property name="test3" value="UPPERCASE" />

    <regexp id="all.uppercase" pattern="^[A-Z]+$" />

    <condition property="test1.isUppercase" value="true" else="false">
        <matches string="${test1}">
            <regexp refid="all.uppercase" />
        </matches>
    </condition>

    <condition property="test2.isUppercase" value="true" else="false">
        <matches string="${test2}">
            <regexp refid="all.uppercase" />
        </matches>
    </condition>

    <condition property="test3.isUppercase" value="true" else="false">
        <matches string="${test3}">
            <regexp refid="all.uppercase" />
        </matches>
    </condition>

    <echo message="test1 uppercase? ${test1.isUppercase}" />
    <echo message="test2 uppercase? ${test2.isUppercase}" />
    <echo message="test3 uppercase? ${test3.isUppercase}" />
</target>
```

Comment: I will take the uppercase value from Jenkins build parameter, so I mentioned as: <property name="test4" value="${MyValue}" />. But it shows as false, it is not taking my parameter value. Any inputs for this ?

Comment: This depends on your Jenkins job configuration. Are you using pipeline, or a traditional config with an "invoke Ant" step? If it's the latter, you will need to pass the parameter as a property in the "Properties" field of the invoke ant step.